# Python Import Hooks and __main__

Tags: python, import

[PEP 302](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/) defines a way for user code to hook into the import process and intercept imports.

However, this only works for imports that occur *after* some code has run to register the import hook.

Almost by definition, no code runs before the `__main__` module, which is the script that is initially run. I haven't had any luck trying to get my import hooks (which do some useful things) to intercept the code being loaded for the `__main__` module.

Is there any way forward that I'm missing, or am I just out of luck? I can accept having my import hooks not perform their transformations on the `__main__` module, but it would be nice if they did.

Comment: The hooks are added at runtime, hence, by the semanthics of `import`, you cannot modified how a program behaves *before* setting the hook with the imported module. You should either modify the main program to apply the hook before, or live without the hook for the main program.

Comment: That was what I thought, although I was hoping that there would be some other way! I've been trying increasingly hacky things to do it (execl, stack introspection, reload(), etc.) and haven't had any luck yet, but I have a gut feeling it may be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried importing inside main like this?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import foo
    # Rest of code here
```

Comment: This is possible, but the `$ Rest of code here` won't get passed through the import hooks. It's basically what I'm doing now (i.e. only `foo` and other imports get the import hooks) and I want to see if there is any way improve it